# Return list of docments according to a substring search on user input

Tags: java, mongodb, substring

I'm trying to do this:

```
db.wines.find({wineName: /mast/i})
```

This query is to find all documents that in WineName have mast like substring and on MongoSH it works.
Now I'm trying to do it in Java with the following code:

```java
public ArrayList<Wine> findWineByPrefix (String prefix) throws WineNotExistsException {
    final MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"));
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("Wines");
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("wines");
    Wine wine = null;
    ArrayList<Wine> wines = new ArrayList<>();
    **MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find(Filters.eq("wineName", "/" + prefix + "/i")).iterator()**;
    if (!cursor.hasNext()){
        throw new WineNotExistsException("No wine found with "+ prefix);
    } else {
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
           .
           .
           .
```

That collection find doesn't work on code. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Pattern to create regex in mongo

```
collection.find(Filters.eq("wineName", Pattern.compile("mast(?i)"))).iterator()
```